# download for local access using wget (partial conversion of the links)

Tags: wget

I have downloaded a website using `wget` with the flags specified below.

```
wget --output-file=german.txt -m -p -k -np german.about.com/ &
```

(I'm trying to boost my language skills :) )

The thing is that it has mirrored correctly the website but only part of links were converted to local.

Some of the links have remained unaltered, still pointing to the online files even though the corresponding files were downloaded **(I checked)**.

Do you have any ideas on why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the `-k` option is for. There is some further info about it in this [tutorial](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/).